# Method Visible of Worksheet fails, but code runs successfully

Tags: vba, excel

The following line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

generates the error:

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

But if I click play in the debugger, execution finishes without a problem. So the line causes my code to go into the debugger. But it continues if I click play.

Why?

**EDIT1**: Here is a screenshot where you can see that the debugger has stopped (with the error code written above) but you can also see in the immediate window that the Visible property exists.[image: Note I have made some changes to the code to try to fix the problem since I originally posted the question, but I have the same error]

**EDIT2**: I tried setting wks as Variant instead of object and setting `wks.Visible=True` instead of `wks.visible = xlSheetVisible`. Neither of the changes helped. I still get the same error:

[image]

Comment: Do you use `On Error Goto` or `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Also what is being called by `vSheets(i, 1)`?  Are you sure that is a valid sheet name?

Comment: Yes, vSheets(i, 1) is a valid sheet name. It does not go to error. When I click on play it actually sets the visibility just like I want it.

Comment: @user1283776 what's "Play"?

Comment: I mean the green play button in the VBE. You have the play, pause and stop buttons. When I hit play, the script continues.

Comment: Try changing the syntax to `wks.Visible = True`

Comment: Is `wks` set to a valid reference?

Comment: @Chirstmas: I tried it in my second edit

Comment: @Mat's Mug: Look at the screenshots. Determining by the immediate and locals window it looks valid to me. But there is something I am not understanding here, so I dunno.

Comment: `Debug.Print wks.Name` right before you run the visible code.  What does it return in the immediate window?

Comment: Maybe the worksheet is protected and does not allow you to modify it?

Comment: @CodeKid: Good idea. I checked this before, and they weren't protected.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to one of the sheets that is actually a chart and is called cashf. If I remove it from vSheets, I get no more errors. But I still don't know what is wrong with cashf, and why I get errors on the Energispar sheet which is a normal sheet. But all errors disappear if I remove cashf.

Comment: I was wrong initially. When I clicked on the "play" button in the IDE, the code would continue, but the action on that line was not completed successfully. So maybe there is such a thing as a non-terminal error.

Comment: I arrived at a solution, but I still don't understand why I got the error I got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220765/looped-charts-and-sheets-as-variants-unsuccessfully-why-did-i-get-an-error-on-t

Answer (score 5):

I found a similar issue after the code worked no worries for weeks.
Eventually found that somehow I had set workbook protection (and not sheet protection as intended). This prevented simple sheet unhide actions through the normal user interface without giving any hint at the fact that workbook protection was set preventing structure changes!

Answer (score 0):

Tried a modified version of your code - this seemed to work for me:

```
            Sub TestSub()
                Dim Sheets(4) As Worksheet
                Dim x As Worksheet
                Dim i As Integer
                For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
                    Set Sheets(i) = x
                    i = i + 1
                Next

                ToggleAllSheets Sheets(), xlSheetVisible
            End Sub

            Public Sub ToggleAllSheets(ByRef XlSheets() As Worksheet, xlVis As XlSheetVisibility)
                Dim xlSheet As Variant
                For Each xlSheet In XlSheets
                    If xlSheet.Visible <> xlVis Then
                        xlSheet.Visible = xlVis
                    End If
                Next

            End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I arrived at a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220765/looped-charts-and-sheets-as-variants-unsuccessfully-why-did-i-get-an-error-on-t

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error:

```
Error 1004: Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

In my case the problem was, that the code tried to hide the currently active sheet. So I just had to set `ActiveSheet` to another (visible) sheet.

Comment: It usually works without any problem to hide the active sheet. Why were you getting problems when hiding the active sheet?

Comment: Well, I have no idea - but maybe because the sheet was just being created by code before (in the same loop)?
But after that change the 1004 error was gone.