# Looped charts and worksheets as sheets unsuccessfully. Exactly what caused the errors?

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to loop charts and sheets as variants.

```
Sub ShowSheets(vSheets() As Variant)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        Dim wks As Variant
        Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))
        wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next i

End Sub
```

`vSheets()` holds the names of the following sheets and charts:

```
SheetName1
SheetName2
ChartName1
SheetName3
SheetName4
```

The subrutine was unsuccessful. I got an error on row `wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible` when `wks` was the worksheet named `SheetName3`.

The error was:

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

Why did I get an error on that specific line?

The following subroutine was also unsuccessful:

```
Sub ShowSheets(vSheets() As Variant)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next i

End Sub
```

I got an error on in the same situation. On the row `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible`, when `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Name` was `SheetName3`. I don't understand why the subroutine above did not work.

I figure that I should have gotten an error when wks was the chart. That I would have understood. I don't understand why I got the error when wks was the first worksheet after the chart.

The following subroutine, works, but I still can't figure out why I got the error where I got it in the subroutines above:

**What caused the errors in the first two subrutines? Why did I get errors when the worksheet was `SheetName3`?**

```
Sub ShowSheets(vSheets() As Variant)

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Worksheet" Then
            ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

    For i = LBound(vSheets, 1) To UBound(vSheets, 1)
        Debug.Print (TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))))
        If TypeName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))) = "Chart" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Charts(vSheets(i, 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It will be helpful if, rather than saying "I got an error on this line", if you would also include **what the error message says**. I'm guessing subscript out of range, which would resolve with: `Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i))`.

Comment: Of course, sorry, the error is: Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Is `vSheets` a multidimensional array? Your code will not compile nor execute unless it is a multidimensional array. Please consider providing enough informatino for others to troubleshoot, without having to ask 30 questions for clarification.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe you cannot change the visibility of a chart, unless the worksheet that contains it is already visible. So first making all the worksheets visible like you did solves it.

Comment: @user1283776 I was able to reproduce your error when a sheet is hidden and the workbook is protected. Is your workbook protected?

Comment: The.worksheets were not protected