# Excel workbook sheets won't unhide

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that has three tabs.  Two of which are hidden.  When I try an unhide the hidden worksheets worksheets the unhide option is greyed out.  I have opened the project window in VBA IDE and can see that the Visible options are set to `0- xlSheetHidden` for the two sheets.  I have tried to change the visibility here to `-1 -xlSheetVisable` but I get the error:

Unable to set the Visibility property of the Worksheet Class.

I have also tied to unhide the sheets with the following code:

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()    
    'Unhide all sheets in workbook.    
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
End Sub
```

But I get the error:

> Run-time 'Visible of object'_Worksheet' failed

The worksheets do exist and there are no passwords or any protection anywhere in the workbook.

Comment: Is the workbook or any worksheet protected?

Comment: workbook not protected, the sheet I can see is not protected, unsure for the two sheets I can't see

Comment: Have a looke [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220765/looped-charts-and-worksheets-as-sheets-unsuccessfully-exactly-what-caused-the-e) to see what OP there did to resolve the issue

Comment: try `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then ws.Unprotect`   
 to check if the hidden sheets are protected

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the workbook is not protected? Press `Alt - T - P - W` to check

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I've never had any success using `ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible`.  I always use:

`ws.Visible = True`

and it always works!

Comment: That should not make a difference :) The value of `True` is `-1`.. Try this in immediate window `?True=xlSheetVisible` or `?True=-1`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I agree.  It shouldn't make a difference **but** it does seem to.  Maybe the internal enumeration of `xlSheetVisible` is wrong and VBA sees it as 0 when it should be -1.

Comment: Have never see a scenario where VBA intepretted xlSheetVisible as 0 :)